# How can I override the active_model_serializer json_key for my application?

Tags: json, serialization, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

Using [ActiveModelSerializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers), I would like to serialize my books resource for all requests, as example for `/books` and `/books/:id`, with a singular `payload` key and then the returned data.

**/books**

```
{
 payload: [{},{},{}]
{
```

**/books/:id**

```
{
 payload: {}
{
```

What I've tried:

#### 1.  Using the `:json_api` adapter

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
```

The `data` key will be applied.

```
{
   data: [{},{},{}]
}

{
   data: {}
}
```

#### 2.  Using the `json` adapter and `root` in controller

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json
```

I can specify the `root`

```
render json: Book.all, root: 'payload'
```

Returns as desired

```
{
   payload: [{},{},{}]
}

{
   payload: {}
}
```

But I would prefer to not repeat this on every render.

### 3.  Using the `json` adapter and overriding `json_key`

```
 class BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  def json_key
    'payload'
  end
end
```

I liked this solution except it returns the pluralized `payload` when serializing an array or resources

```
{
   payloads: [{},{},{}]
}

{
   payload: {}
}
```

### How can I set a default root for my serializer?

(or model or controller or application if that would be preferred)